# Cannot download fabric-sdk-go even if the GOPTH is configured

Tags: go, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am a newbie in GOlang and Hyperledger fabric, I was just configuring the environment. But I got a weird error that is given bellow

```
 user1@NTP-145UBUNTU:~$ go env
 GOARCH="amd64"
 GOBIN=""
 GOEXE=""
 GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
 GOHOSTOS="linux"
 GOOS="linux"
 GOPATH="/usr/lib/go-1.6/bin"
 GORACE=""
 GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.6"
 GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
 GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
 CC="gcc"
 GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
 CXX="g++"
 CGO_ENABLED="1"
 user1@NTP-145UBUNTU:~$ sudo go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go
 [sudo] password for user1: 
 package github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

It is saying that my GOPATH env variable is not set. I have configured it and its is showing in evn variable list also. If anyone in here faced this issue please help me. please note : I am using ubuntu 16 LTS

thanks in advance.

Comment: First, that is not a valid GOPATH, it should not point to a bin directory. Second, sudo is running the command in a new environment without your env variables. You should never use sudo with `go get`

Comment: ^ but you should also update your go version currently go 1.10 is out which means the lowest supported version is go 1.8

Comment: Thank you please let me update the version,

Answer (score 2):

You are executing `go get` with `sudo`. That will cause all your env variables to be lost, as the command gets executed as user `root`.

Usually this should not be necessary. $GOPATH is usually set to `$HOME/go/`. This is also the default value. You should set $GOPATH to this value. After that you do not have to call `go get` with `sudo`.

And as pizza lord suggested, you should update your go version.

Comment: The problem was the version, The version which I installed has a bug, something like the GOPATH won't be consider if there is no go workspace configured. So i just removed my Go Lang and installed new version into the /home/go folder. then I configured the path by using GOROOT path variable.its working fine now.

Comment: Ah, ok. Ubuntu has some very broken packages. Glad you could sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the existing golang version packaged with ubuntu. Update you golang version to 1.9 or latest .

```
$ sudo apt-get remove golang-go 
$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gophers/archive
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install golang-1.10-go

Update ~/.bash_profile with golang variables
export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin"
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

Comment: Yes I tried exactly what you said . Thank you very much.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved it. It helps others .

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible mistakes

1. you have not configured `$GOPATH` correctly.

try this.

```
 mkdir ~/go-workspace
```

and in your `.bashrc` file, append this

```
export GOPATH=~/go-workspace
```

2. You are using `go get` with `sudo`.

try :

```
go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go
```

if you get permission denied error, try

```
sudo chown user1 $(echo $GOPATH)
```

Comment: I tried and fixed by re installing new version of Go lang. Thank you very much